# Como agendar várias tarefas no spring boot de forma dinamica?

Tags: spring-boot, scheduler

Tenho uma aplicação em spring boot e a mesma tem vários jobs que serão executados de tempos em tempos e esse intervalo de tempo tem que ser recuperado no banco de dados.

Na classe ScheduledConfig temos a recuperação dos dados:

```
@Bean(name = "jobConfirmaPagamento")
@Primary
public String jobConfirmaPagamento(){
    logger.info("Consultando o tempo de execução para o rotina CONFIRMA-PAGAMENTO.");
    return configuracaoServico.consultarTempoExecucaoConfirmaPagamento();
}

@Bean(name = "jobLiberacaoPagamento")
@Lazy
public String jobLiberacaoPagamento() {
    logger.info("Consultando o tempo de execução para a rotina LIBERACAO-PAGAMENTO");
    return configuracaoServico.consultarTempoExecucaoLiberacaoPagamento();
}

@Bean(name = "jobSaldoProvisionado")
@Lazy
public String jobSaldoProvisionado() {
    logger.info("Consultando o tempo de execução para a rotina SALDO-PROVISIONADO");
    return configuracaoServico.consultarTempoExecucaoSaldoProvisionado();
}

@Bean(name = "jobSaldoDepositoJudicial")
@Lazy
public String jobSaldoDepositoJudicial() {
    logger.info("Consultando o tempo de execução para a rotina SALDO-DEPOSITO-JUDICIAL");
    return configuracaoServico.consultarTempoExecucaoSaldoDepositoJudicial();
}
```

Porém apenas o jobConfirmaPagamento está sendo disparado.

Answer (score 2):

Para isso você pode utilizar [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)

Coloquei um modelo abaixo onde estou usando `@Scheduled` para schedular o job, nele estou injetando um bean contendo a propriedade buscada do banco contendo a expressão cron:

```
@Bean
public String getSchedulerConfigJobConfirmaPagamento() {
   return configRepository.findOne(Constants.SCHEDULER_JOB_CONFIRMA_PAGAMENTO).getConfigValue(); // Aqui será retornado sua String contendo o cron (0 12 * * MON por exemplo)
}

@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "#{@getSchedulerConfigJobConfirmaPagamento}")
public void runJobConfirmaPagamento() {
    ... // Aqui você possui a chamada para a lógica de seu job de fato
}
```

A idéia é você ter um bean para cada configuração cron, e usá-las de acordo para cada atividade